# Case insensitive search in database with an index?

Tags: database, postgresql, search, case-insensitive

I'm using Postgres.

I have a table of Artices in my database, with a column url for url slugs. These are so that I can display the articles in that table on a website as not "`example.com/23323`" but instead as "`example.com/Funny_Thing_Happened_to_Me`".
This was straightforward enough to implement, and then as the number of articles grew, I added an index to the table on the url slugs.

I have since realized that while I want to be able to display capitalized letters in the urls, I want them to be case insensitive in terms of what the user types in, and I want to enforce uniqueness on the urls in a case insensitive manner.

**Is there a straightforward way to quickly search based on a text column in a case insensitive way, and also enforce uniqueness in a case insensitive way?**

I've tried conducting the searches with something like `lower(url) =` but that causes Postgres to decide not to use the index at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a [functional index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createindex.html) :

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix_test1 on articles (lower(url));
```

If you're on 8.4 and can install a contrib module, then also take a look at the [citext](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/citext.html) type.  It abstracts away all the lower/UPPER stuff and is slightly better performing.

Comment: Thanks this seems to be the way to go. Only problem is that I can't directly create the index due to existing clashes on the lower(url), but I can't see any way around that other than fixing the data.

Comment: @williamjones: Add the index as non-unique for the moment to get the performance benefit.  Then fix the uniqueness,create a new unique index, and drop the old one.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE textfield ILIKE 'value%';
```

Is this what you are looking for?
What do you mean by "enforce uniqueness in a case insensitive way"?

Or this if you want to stick to the "lower()":

```
SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE UPPER(textfield) LIKE (UPPER('value') || '%');
```